# Запуск файла из одной из папок

Tags: c#

Необходимо запустить файл из папки. Если файла там нет проверить в другой если и там нет то выдать ошибку. Ниже код он в принципе работает но если файл есть в первой папке то он сразу выдаёт ошибку. Как сделать чтобы сообщения об ошибке появлялось если файла нет не в одной из папок?

```
try     
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminUI\bin\i386\rc.exe");
}
catch { }
try
{
    Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminUI\bin\i386\rc.exe");
}
catch
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Ошибка файл не найден \"rc.exe\" ", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: код вообще неправильно написан, и всегда будет испольнять 2 файла (по край не мерее пытаться)

Comment: И, на будущее, никогда не пишите catch не обработав исключение, потом сами не будите понимать, где ошибка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const string AppPath = @"Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminUI\bin\i386\rc.exe";
var x64 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
var x86 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);

var isExecuted = false;
foreach (var rootPath in new[] { x64, x86 })
{
    var path = Path.Combine(rootPath, AppPath);
    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        Process.Start(path);
        isExecuted = true;
        break;
    }
}

if (!isExecuted)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка файл не найден \"rc.exe\" ", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

С использование LINQ:

```
const string AppPath = @"Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminUI\bin\i386\rc.exe";

var path = FindApp(AppPath);
if (path != null)
{
    Process.Start(path);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Ошибка файл не найден \"rc.exe\" ", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}

static string FindApp(string appPath)
{
    var x64 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
    var x86 = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86);
    return new[]{x64,x86}.Select(x => Path.Combine(x, appPath)).FirstOrDefault(File.Exists);
}
```

Comment: Отлично, что использовали переменные среды окружения =) И было бы даже универсальное решение, если бы нужна была возможность более чем из 2ух источников загружать файл.

Comment: А если файл запускается с аргументами типа?
                startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Citrix\ICA Client\pnagent.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = "/CitrixShortcut: (1) /QLaunch \"65:Risk\"";

Comment: @Павел Process.Start поддерживает перегрузку для ProcessStartInfo. Не понял ваш вопрос... Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(path, arguments))

Comment: У меня есть файл который запускается с аргументами  Process _process = new Process();

                ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();


                startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\pnagent.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = "/CitrixShortcut: (1) /QLaunch \"65:Risk\"";

                _process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                _process.Start();

Comment: @Павел так в чем же проблема с аргументами??? Пожалуйста запускайте!

Comment: А всё разобрался

Comment: @pavelip: У вас та же проблема, что и в предыдущем ответе. `FindApp` не гарантирует наличие приложения: это такой же race condition, как и с проверкой флага в другом потоке без мьютекса. Корректно избежать обработки исключения невозможно.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь File.Exists методом, для проверки.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx

```
    string path = @"C:\Program Files{0}\Microsoft Configuration Manager\AdminUI\bin\i386\rc.exe";

    if (File.Exists(string.Format(path, string.Empty)))
        Process.Start(string.Format(path, string.Empty));
    else if (File.Exists(string.Format(path, " (x86)")))
        Process.Start(string.Format(path, " (x86)"));
    else
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Ошибка файл не найден \"rc.exe\" ", "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
```

Comment: А можно поподробней как это сделать?

Comment: переписал Ваш код

Comment: Это race condition между проверкой файла и его запуском. Вы _не можете_ обойтись без try/catch-блока.

Comment: Если необходимо отслеживать другие исключения, которые могут возникнуть при выполнении команды, можно обернуть Process.Start в try\catch - здесь ответ на вопрос, а не production код, верно?

Comment: огромное спасибо

Comment: @alexsuslin: Это не «другие исключения», это «файл нот фаунд». Проверка `File.Exists` избыточна и ничего не гарантирует.

Comment: как бы в вопросе про это и спрашивалось

Answer (score 1):

Использование `File.Exists` неверно, так как эта информация устаревает как только функция заканчивает работу. (См. секцию exogenous exceptions [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/vexing-exceptions).)

Вы должны просто проверить список адресов:

```
bool TryRun(string path)
{
    try
    {
        Process.Start(path);
        return true;
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}

bool found = false;
for (var path in paths)
{
    found = TryRun(path);
    if (found)
        break;
}

if (!found) ...
```